# A dynamic text field in QuickSight dashboard

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a dashboard and I want to show when the dataset was created. I have a column in my  dataset and I was trying to use QS Parameters or Calculated Field, but no luck. I can create a static parameter and output that value in a title of visualization, however I can't dynamically select `max(my_last_date_filed)` from the dataset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Insight type, where I defined variable as following: `Maximum.timeValue.formattedValue`, which solved my problem